# Why won't a boolean object property update?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, this, factory

I have an array of objects. Each object has a method that *should* update a boolean property in the same object called 'found'.

When I call the function, the property does not update. I am not sure why.

I thought that the 'found' property would be accessible but it isn't??

I have created a minimal version of the problem here:
https://codepen.io/sspboyd/pen/XWYKMrv?editors=0011

```
const gen_s = function () { // generate and return the object
  let found = false;

  const change_found = function () {
    found = true;
  };

  const update = function () {
    change_found();
  };

  return {
    change_found,
    found,
    update
  };
};

const s_arr = []; // initialize an array

s_arr.push(gen_s()); // add a new s object to the array

console.log(s_arr[0].found); // returns 'false'

s_arr.forEach((s) => {
  s.update();
});

console.log(s_arr[0].found);
```

Comment: When you return the object, `found` is a "snapshot" of what `found` is currently in the closure (which is `false`) - so it does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `change_found` function changes the value of `found`, it's changing the value pointed to by your `let found` variable, but the object returned by your `gen_s` function still points to the old value.

You can fix your code using the 'holder' pattern, like this:

```js
const gen_s = function () { // generate and return the object
  let foundHolder = {value: false};

  const change_found = function () {
    foundHolder.value = true;
  };

  const update = function () {
    change_found();
  };

  return {
    change_found,
    foundHolder,
    update
  };
};

const s_arr = []; // initialize an array

s_arr.push(gen_s()); // add a new s object to the array

console.log(s_arr[0].foundHolder.value); // returns 'false'

s_arr.forEach((s) => {
  s.update();
});

console.log(s_arr[0].foundHolder.value);
```

Or even better, use a class:

```js
class S {
  constructor() { this.found = false; }
  change_found() { this.found = true; }
  update() { this.change_found(); }
}
const s_arr = [];
s_arr.push(new S());
console.log(s_arr[0].found);

s_arr.forEach(s => s.update());
console.log(s_arr[0].found);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful response @andrew-parks!!
Am I correct in assuming that the relevant difference here is between changing a variable that gets assigned to the generated object vs creating an object holder and changing it's 'value'??

I'd like to learn more about why Javascript works like this. Is there a term I can look up for this type of variable declaration/referencing?

Comment: @sspboyd Search for "javascript scope". Your issue is essentially the same situation as what happens when you pass a variable to a function as a parameter. Inside that function, if you set the parameter to something different, you're setting your own local variable to reference a different value. The code that called your function will have its own variable that still references the original value.